# server doesn't interpret ruby (maybe a Passenger issue)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, passenger

I'm deploying a RoR app.
Tried Ubuntu 13.10 + Nginx + Passenger and Ubuntu 12.04 + Apache2 + Passenger

and got the same situation each time:

View's raw code shows up in my browser instead of rendering normal pages.
I.e. the browser doesn't interpret it.

In development mode on local server it works perfectly, though.

This is probably a Passenger issue.
Which portion of code can help understand that?

Where the problem can be?

Comment: Just so you know, it's not the browser's responsibility to interpret your ruby code, it's the server's. The browser just gets the rendered page from the server.

Comment: Where is your server physically, how are you connecting to it from the client machine (where the browser is running)? The browser doesn't interpret ruby code, it interprets html and Javascript. It's the server that interprets it, in this case, Passenger.

Comment: I know... OK, I should rename the topic.

Comment: it's VPS hosting which is physically far away :) I'm using ssh to connect to it

Comment: >> in this case, Passenger — I suspect that it can be passenger yet I've no idea what can be wrong there. Which portion of code can help understand that?